# How to Prove Unboundedness

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, martingales

Suppose I have a submartingale $X_k$, what results/theorems can be useful if I want to show that $X_k$ is unbounded in the limit. There are results (basically bounding $\mathbb{E}X_k$) for *convergence* of submartinagles. But, I wanted to show that a submartingale goes to infinity in the limit for my research.

Take the submartingale $X_0=0, X_{k+1}=X_k+1$ for instance.

Comment: Your example is not really enlightening since $X_k$ can be calculated explicitly and is actually deterministic.

Comment: @saz, take $X_{k+1} = X_k + \cal{U}(0.5,1)$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

If the submartingale is of the form $$X_k = \sum_{j=1}^k \xi_j$$ where $\xi_j \in L^1$ are independent identically distributed random variables, then, by the strong law of large numbers,

$$\frac{X_k}{k} \to \mathbb{E}\xi_1 \qquad \text{almost surely as $k \to \infty$.}$$

This means that $$\lim_{k \to \infty} X_k = \infty$$ whenenver $\mathbb{E}\xi_1 \neq  0$. (Note that $\mathbb{E}\xi_1 \geq 0$ holds in any case since $(X_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a submartingale.)